# revert Scaffold command

Tags: git, entity-framework, nuget, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

**Scaffolding** is a powerful feature and we can generate models, controllers 
and views very fast from the package manager under visual studio.

But if you submit the wrong command, how to revert it ?

For example :

```
Scaffold Controller Person -Repository
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be wonderfull if there is a `Scafforld-Revert`, but unfortunetely there is no such a thing.

This can be done with a :

```
git revert <commit>
```

> **Reverting vs. Resetting** :
>
> It's important to understand that git revert
>   undoes a single commit—it does not “revert” back to the previous state
>   of a project by removing all subsequent commits.  In Git, this is
>   actually called a reset, not a revert.

See here : [Atlassian Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes)